# How to color quotes block in red

Tags: code, highlighting

How can I color the block `std::complex<T>` in red as shown in the picture?

[image]

Comment: `\textcolor{red}{...}` using the package `xcolor`

Comment: @Fran - I think a combination of `\textcolor` and `\colorbox` is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution that creates a macro, called `\mycolorbox`, which combines the `\colorbox` and `\textcolor` macros of the `xcolor` package.

[image]

You're obviously free to change the colors (`red`, `MistyRose`) currently used in the definition of `\mycolorbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor} % 'svgnames' for 'MistyRose'
\newcommand\mycolorbox[1]{\colorbox{MistyRose}{\textcolor{red}{\textsf{#1}}}}
\begin{document}
\mycolorbox{std::complex<T>} \quad \mycolorbox{a, b}
\end{document}
```